Given a complex square matrix $A$, and if $A_{n} \rightarrow A$ then for a polynomial $p$, prove that $p(A_{n}) \rightarrow p(A)$
This is the problem asked in one of our exercises
Let $p$ be the polynomial with complex coefficients and $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ be a norm on $C^{n \times n}$. Let $A \in C^{n \times n}$ and $A_{n}$ be a sequence of matrices in $C^{n \times n}$ such that $\Vert A_{n} - A \Vert \rightarrow 0$. Then prove that $\Vert p(A_{n}) - p(A) \Vert \rightarrow 0$.
MY APPROACH
First we have to prove that $\Vert A_{n}^{k} - A^{k}\Vert$ goes to zero for a integer $k$. So I was trying for $k = 2$ which I couldn't prove. This is what I tried
\begin{align*}
\Vert A_{n}^{2} - A^{2} \Vert &= \Vert (A_{n}-A)(A_{n}+A) + AA_{n} - A_{n}A \Vert \\
&\leq \Vert (A_{n}-A)(A_{n}+A) \Vert + \Vert AA_{n} - A_{n}A \Vert \\
\end{align*}
The first term goes to zero but how do I show that second term goes to zero ?. Like I can say that $A_{n}A \rightarrow A^{2}$ and $AA_{n} \rightarrow A^{2}$ but don't know how to prove $\Vert AA_{n} - A_{n}A \Vert$ goes to zero.
ANSWER AFTER DISCUSSION
Thanks to @pranay and @ClearlyIncompetentGuy.
We have to prove that if $A_{n} \rightarrow  A$ then $p(A_{n}) \rightarrow p(A)$. If we consider the polynomial to have degree $m$, then
\begin{align*}
    \Vert{p(A_{n}) - p(A)}\Vert &= \Vert{a_{m}(A_{n}^{m} - A^{m}) + a_{m - 1}(A_{n}^{m - 1} - A^{m - 1}) + \cdots + a_{1}(A_{1} - A)}\Vert \\
    &\leq \vert{a_{m}}\vert\Vert{A_{n}^{m} - A^{m}}\Vert + \vert{a_{m-1}}\vert\Vert{A_{n}^{m - 1} - A^{m - 1}}\Vert + \cdots + \vert{a_{1}}\vert\Vert{A_{1} - A}\Vert
\end{align*}
If we can prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \Vert{A_{n}^{k} - A^{k}}\Vert = 0$ for any $1 \leq k \leq m$ then we are done (because RHS will go to zero in the above inequality). We will use induction to prove this. \
For $k = 1$ is true as it's given which will be our base. Assume that it is true for $k - 1$. For $k$, consider
\begin{align*}
    \Vert{A_{n}^{k} - A^{k}}\Vert = \Vert{(A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1})A_{n} + A^{k-1}(A_{n} - A)}\Vert
\end{align*}
Here if we apply triangle inequality then $A_{n}$ is the term that will give the problem. We will manipulate as follows
\begin{align*}
    \Vert{A_{n}^{k} - A^{k}}\Vert &= \Vert{(A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1})(A_{n} - A + A) + A^{k-1}(A_{n} - A)}\Vert \\
    &= \Vert{(A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1})(A_{n} - A) + (A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1})A + A^{k-1}(A_{n} - A)}\Vert \\
    &\leq \Vert{(A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1})(A_{n} - A)}\Vert + \Vert{(A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1})A}\Vert + \Vert{A^{k-1}(A_{n} - A)}\Vert \\
    &\leq \Vert{A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1}}\Vert\Vert{A_{n} - A}\Vert + \Vert{A_{n}^{k-1} - A^{k-1}}\Vert\Vert{A}\Vert + \Vert{A^{k-1}}\Vert\Vert{A_{n} - A}\Vert
\end{align*}
Applying limit I will get required result.

Please don't write a sequence $A_n$ for matrices in $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$.  Your life will be a bit easier here if you argue that you can assume WLOG that the norm is submultiplicative.

Does something like this not work?
$$\lVert A A_n - A_n A \rVert = \lVert A A_n - A_n A_n + A_n A_n - A_n A \rVert \\
\leq \lVert A A_n - A_n A_n \rVert + \lVert A_n A_n - A_n A \rVert 
\\
= \lVert (A - A_n) A_n \rVert + \lVert A_n( A_n - A) \rVert.$$

Thanks. I was trying to do some manipulation but nothing came out. I will have to see if I can apply to induction to prove for general $k$ that is $\Vert A_{n}^{k} - A^{k} \Vert$ goes to zero.

As @user8675309 pointed out, using $n$ for indexing the sequence and for the dimension of the matrix is a bit confusing, so let's use $n$ for indexing the sequence and $m$ for dimension.
While the answer by @ClearlyIncompetentGuy addresses your specific question, you are still left with $\Vert A_n \Vert$, which depends on $n$ and is not readily bounded. Instead you can do the following:
$$
A_n^2 - A^2 = (A_n-A)^2 + (A_n-A)A + A (A_n - A).
$$
Using triangle inequality and submultiplicativity, we get
$$
\Vert A_n^2 - A^2 \Vert \le \Vert A_n-A\Vert^2 + \Vert A_n-A \Vert \Vert A\Vert + \Vert A\Vert \Vert A_n - A\Vert.
$$
The nice thing about this decomposition is that you get $\Vert A\Vert$ instead of $\Vert A_n\Vert$ on the RHS, so you can simply use the fact that $\Vert A_n - A\Vert \rightarrow 0$.
You can of course repeat the same for any $A_n^k - A^k$ by induction on $k$. I will leave it to you to figure out, but if you want, I can update my answer to explain how that works.

Why is $\lVert A_n \rVert$ not bounded? $A_n$ is a convergent sequence in a normed space, so there should be a constant that bounds $\lVert A_n \rVert$, right?

@ClearlyIncompetentGuy It is indeed bounded and I didn’t say it’s not bounded. All I meant to say was that you have to add another step like $\Vert A_n \Vert \le \Vert A_n - A\Vert + \Vert A \Vert$. My point was that this step can be avoided from the beginning by doing the decomposition as in my answer.

Here you can just use the fact $p\colon C^{n\times n}\to C^{n\times n}$ is always a continuos map. However, this means that for each sequence $A_n$ convergent to some $A$, then $p(A_n)$ is convergent to $p(A)$.

In the course continuity was not taught (where $p : C^{n \times n} \rightarrow C^{n \times n}$). So most probably I can't use this argument.
